# ExtJS datefield - UI selection resets the URL # (fragment identifier)

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs3

I have created an ExtJS 3.4 `datefield` component inside a `<form>`, but whenever I click on the date picker, it sets the URL # (fragment identifier) to blank.

This causes the page to scroll to the top of the screen; scrolling back down to the date picker reveals that the click has had no effect on the date picker (it still is visible with the original date selected).

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated...

Comment: have you tried it on a blank page. I have never had this behaviour on datefileds. see you still get that on a empty page with just datefiled in it. if it still occurs please past some code,, or you can try to debug the click event of the field itself.

Comment: check your javascript console, there should be an error. datefield normally cancels the click event after opening its container.